# How to protect against DDOS attack socketserver python

Tags: python, security, ddos, socketserver

I'm planning on incorporating a server into an application I'm developing (none of the data being transferred will be sensitive). I've set up port forwarding on my router that points to the server on the network. Here is a snippet of the server side code:

```
import time
import threading
import socketserver
import ssl


class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # Each new request is handled by this function.
        data = str(self.request.recv(4096), 'utf-8')
        print('Request received on {}'.format(time.ctime()))
        print('{} wrote: {}'.format(self.client_address[0], data))
        cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
        response = bytes("{}: {}".format(cur_thread.name, data), 'utf-8')
        self.request.sendall(response)


class TLSTCPServer(socketserver.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, request_handler_class, certfile, keyfile, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
                 bind_and_activate=True):
        socketserver.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, request_handler_class, bind_and_activate)
        self.certfile = certfile
        self.keyfile = keyfile
        self.ssl_version = ssl_version

    def get_request(self):
        newsocket, fromaddr = self.socket.accept()
        connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                                     server_side=True,
                                     certfile=self.certfile,
                                     keyfile=self.keyfile,
                                     ssl_version=self.ssl_version)
        return connstream, fromaddr


class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, TLSTCPServer):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 6001

    # Creates a server that handles each request on a separate thread. "cert.pem" is the TLS certificate and "key.pem"
    # is the TLS private key (kept only on the server).
    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler, "cert.pem", "key.pem")
    ip, port = server.server_address

    print('Started server\n')
    server.serve_forever()
```

And here is the client code:

```
import socket
import time
import ssl

HOST = 'localhost'  # This should be the server's public IP when used in production code
PORT = 6001

data = 'Hello!'
start_time = time.time()

try:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock,
                               ca_certs="cert.pem",
                               cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                               ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

    ssl_sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    ssl_sock.sendall(data.encode())

    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = ssl_sock.recv(4096)

    elapsed_tie = round(time.time() - start_time, 2)
    print("Sent:     {}".format(data))
    print("Received: {}".format(received.decode('utf-8')))
    print("Elapsed:  {}s \n".format(elapsed_tie))
    ssl_sock.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(format(e))
```

Note that `cert.pem` and `key.pem` are generated with this command in a Mac or Linux terminal: `openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha512 -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem`

The server uses TLS to secure the data, and requests are handled on separate threads. The amount of computation done for each request will be relatively small, as it would mainly consist of reading and writing small amounts of data to a database with each request.

My main concern is that somebody acting maliciously could figure out what the server's public IP address is and perform a DDOS attack. One way I can think to mitigate this is to deny requests made too frequently from the same client address. Are there any other ways to mitigate such attacks? Also, is running a secure server in Python a good idea or should I be looking elsewhere? Thank you in advance.

--- EDIT ---

I was thinking of checking whether the same user makes too many requests in a certain amount of time. Since the requests are on a timer (say, 5 seconds) any requests made more frequently are deemed suspicious. As long as the incoming requests don't saturate the router's bandwidth, I should, in theory, be able to deny some requests. However, if multiple machines make requests from the same network, I can't just look at the incoming requests' public IP addresses, since I could be denying perfectly valid requests. Is there any ID identifiable to the machine making the request?

Answer (score 1):

When a DDoS attack gets to you it is too late. The packets arrived to your server and are filling up your pipe. No matter what you do, they are already there - many of them. You can discard them but others won't be able to reach you anyway.

DDoS protection must be done uplink, by someone who will have the capacity to decide whether a packet is malicious or not. This is a magical operation which companies such as Cloudflare or Akamai make you pay a lot for.

Another possibility is to change your DNS entry to point is somewhere else during the attack. This is really a nice to have, so that your customers know that your site is "under maintenance, back soon".

Comment: I was thinking of checking whether the same user makes too many requests in a certain amount of time. Since the requests are on a timer (say, 5 seconds) any requests made more frequently are deemed suspicious. As long as the incoming requests don't saturate the router's bandwidth, I should, in theory, be able to deny some requests. However, if multiple machines make requests from the same network, I can't just look at the incoming requests' public IP addresses, since I could be denying perfectly valid requests. Is there any ID identifiable to the machine making the request?

Comment: The first thing you mention is called throttling. This protects (in your case) a user account from being brute-forced. Thge second part (how to identify the devices uniquely) is actually the "magical operation" I mentioned: the ability to decide whether a specific call/connection is legitimate or not. There are no simple solutions to this and DDoS mitigation services sell exactly this knowledge. Realistically, you can protect an account from bruteforce (by throttling IPs and possibly locking the account  - this is a matter of risk analysis) but not much more.